# Getting values of html form elements in Asp.net added dynamically via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hello there i have written some code in jquery to add new input type elements in aspx page! Now I want to fetch values of these elements via ASP.NET! I know if i want to achieve this i will have to store each values in hidden form elements n then fetching hidden element val in cs file! I am curious if i could get a direct/shortcut way to fetch the values of each dynamically added contols in Asp.Net incase there were dozens of elements which were added dynamically in jquery!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give every element you add to your page a class, say "dynamic". Before postback, update a HiddenField like so:

```
var hiddenValues = "";
$(".dynamic").each(function(){
   hiddenValues += $(this).val() + ",";
});

$("#hiddenField").val(hiddenValues);
```

Then access the comma delimited hidden field value in the code behind.

Comment: Thank you so much Troy. You code showed me the rightt way to achieve what i wanted. Im marking it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you add inputs on the client-side, the server doesn't have an object created to access its POST data like it does with your `runat="server"` controls. There are a few options:

1) Use a script to set the value of a `runat="server"` HiddenField before postback.

2) Access `Request.Form["YourInputName"]`.